# Outputting code on new lines in php without using BR

Tags: php

Take this code as an example:

```
$number_of_products=count($_POST['prodcode']);
   for ( $i=0; $i<$number_of_products; $i++){
       $orderdetails.= $_POST['prodcode'][$i]." has the meterage: ".$_POST['meterage'][$i]."<br/>";
   }
```

How can i put each line produced on a new line without using BR.  IE so when its printed by the HTML its output is like:

```
LINE1
LINE2
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a <br />?

Comment: Its for source output!  Thanks for asking, i have the answer below now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $orderdetails.= $_POST['prodcode'][$i]." has the meterage: ".$_POST['meterage'][$i]."<br/>"."\n";
```

I assume your talking about the source code?
cause `\n` creates a new line in a text but not in 
a html page

Answer (score 1):

Use <pre></pre> tags before printing your code (with \n instead of <br />)... Just like...

```
$number_of_products=count($_POST['prodcode']);
echo '<pre>';

for ( $i=0; $i<$number_of_products; $i++){
   $orderdetails.= $_POST['prodcode'][$i]." has the meterage: ".$_POST['meterage'][$i]."\n";

echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `<br/>` your only chance is to wrap each line with some block-level element OR to wrap the whole outcome within a `<pre></pre>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of br, use \n

Example:

```
$orderdetails.= $_POST['prodcode'][$i]." has the meterage: ".$_POST['meterage'][$i]."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

`"\n"` will output a line break only visible in the source code. Any line break that you want to be visible to the end user has to be made unsing a `<br/>` or wrapping the output in a block level element.

Answer (score 0):

For rendered HTML, you have to use a `<br>` (not entirely accurate, as there are are technically other ways to generate breaks, such as `<hr>` and block-level elements, but for the purposes of this question it is accurate enough).

Answer (score 0):

If you are outputting it in an html environment, i think that `<br/>` or `<br>` will be the only chance to create a new line. After all, you can also manage the source outputting by adding `\n\r` at the end of the string.

Basically the following code

```
echo "<div>\n\rThreesome, blablabuli, i'm taking this seriously\n\r</div><br>";
echo "I'm seriously serious";
```

will output html source code

```
<div>
Threesome, blablabuli, i'm taking this seriously
</div><br>I'm seriously serious
```

that will output

```
Threesome, blablabuli, i'm taking this seriously
I'm seriously serious
```